# HPToucHSMART 610 - no sound from my PS3 - Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: nvidia, sound, hdmi, ps3

As my hard drive crashed in my touchsmart 610 - I reinstalled my system on a linux external HDD - but since then when I plug in my PS3 via HDMI to the touchsmart I have no sound. The image from the PS3 is however working in HD perfectly fine

As I have tried mutliple things already. I am starting to be annoyed by this. The sound works perfectly on the computer itself (music, movies etc) but only not from the PS3. When I run `alsamixer` I do not see however any HDMI port active.

Here is the detail of my graphic card - as I heard this may help - and somewhere below the details of the sound.

```
olaf@olaf-TouchSmart-600:~$ lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 12)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2a9a
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port (rev 12) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000d000-0000dfff
    Memory behind bridge: fa000000-fbcfffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000ce000000-00000000dfffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2a9a
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 46
    Memory at f9fffc00 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei
    Kernel modules: mei

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2a9a
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at f9ffc000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2a9a
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
    Memory at f9ff8000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
    Memory behind bridge: fbd00000-fbdfffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000c0200000-00000000c03fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00001000-00001fff
    Memory behind bridge: fbe00000-fbefffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000c0000000-00000000c01fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
    Memory behind bridge: fbf00000-fbffffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000f8f00000-00000000f8ffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2a9a
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at f9ff6000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a6) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=05, subordinate=05, sec-latency=32
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2a9a
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: iTCO_wdt

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2a9a
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
    I/O ports at cc00 [size=8]
    I/O ports at c880 [size=4]
    I/O ports at c800 [size=8]
    I/O ports at c480 [size=4]
    I/O ports at c400 [size=32]
    Memory at f9ff4000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2a9a
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 7
    Memory at f9fff800 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at 0400 [size=32]
    Kernel modules: i2c-i801

00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2a9a
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Memory at f9ffe000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: intel_ips

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT216 [GeForce GT 230M] (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Device 1b0a:903b
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at fa000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at ce000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at dc00 [size=128]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at fbc80000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidia_current_updates, nvidia, nouveau, nvidiafb

02:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3092 Wireless 802.11n 2T/2R PCIe
    Subsystem: Device 15a9:0015
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at fbdf0000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
    Kernel modules: rt2800pci

03:00.0 Multimedia video controller: NEC Corporation Device 0165 (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Avermedia Technologies Inc Device 650b
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 5
    Memory at fbefe000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Memory at fbefd800 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2a9a
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
    I/O ports at e800 [size=256]
    Memory at fbfff000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at f8ffc000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Expansion ROM at fbfc0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

Here is the detail of the sound setting

```
olaf@olaf-TouchSmart-600:~$ lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 12)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2a9a
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port (rev 12) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000d000-0000dfff
    Memory behind bridge: fa000000-fbcfffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000ce000000-00000000dfffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2a9a
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 46
    Memory at f9fffc00 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei
    Kernel modules: mei

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2a9a
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at f9ffc000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2a9a
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
    Memory at f9ff8000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
    Memory behind bridge: fbd00000-fbdfffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000c0200000-00000000c03fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00001000-00001fff
    Memory behind bridge: fbe00000-fbefffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000c0000000-00000000c01fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
    Memory behind bridge: fbf00000-fbffffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000f8f00000-00000000f8ffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2a9a
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at f9ff6000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a6) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=05, subordinate=05, sec-latency=32
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2a9a
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: iTCO_wdt

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2a9a
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
    I/O ports at cc00 [size=8]
    I/O ports at c880 [size=4]
    I/O ports at c800 [size=8]
    I/O ports at c480 [size=4]
    I/O ports at c400 [size=32]
    Memory at f9ff4000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2a9a
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 7
    Memory at f9fff800 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at 0400 [size=32]
    Kernel modules: i2c-i801

00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2a9a
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Memory at f9ffe000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: intel_ips

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT216 [GeForce GT 230M] (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Device 1b0a:903b
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at fa000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at ce000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at dc00 [size=128]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at fbc80000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidia_current_updates, nvidia, nouveau, nvidiafb

02:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3092 Wireless 802.11n 2T/2R PCIe
    Subsystem: Device 15a9:0015
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at fbdf0000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
    Kernel modules: rt2800pci

03:00.0 Multimedia video controller: NEC Corporation Device 0165 (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Avermedia Technologies Inc Device 650b
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 5
    Memory at fbefe000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Memory at fbefd800 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2a9a
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
    I/O ports at e800 [size=256]
    Memory at fbfff000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at f8ffc000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Expansion ROM at fbfc0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

olaf@olaf-TouchSmart-600:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC888 Analog [ALC888 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 1: ALC888 Digital [ALC888 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Answer (score 2):

Open the terminal and type the following:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

This will open alsa-base.conf in gedit, the official text editor on the Gnome desktop. At the very end add the following 1 line to alsa-base.conf file:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=touchsmart
```

Now, save the file and reload alsa using:

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```